# Installing Gitlab Python repos with multiple dependencies

Tags: python, docker, gitlab

I need to make a Docker container with some Python packages that are stored in Gitlab. Package A has dependencies B and C, which are also stored in separate Gitlab repos. They are all under the same group. What is the best way of doing this without creating a new Gitlab with its own SSH key? I'm trying to solve it with `Project Access Tokens` and then specifying the `username` and `access_token` when I run `pip install git+https://<username>:<access_token>@<gitlab-domain>/<group>/mypackageA.git`. This of course works fine for this package, but fails for package B and C since these dependencies are listed in `setup.cfg` in package A as `mypackageB @ git+https://<gitlab-domain>/<group>/mypackageB.git`. Since I can't edit the `setup.cfg` file itself, is there a way to work around this in my Dockerfile? Or is it possible to set up a more general access to the entire group and use it for all the dependencies when I build the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use group tokens instead, and then set `git config --global url."https://${GITLAB_LOGIN}:${GITLAB_PWD}@gitlab".insteadOf https://gitlab` in my Dockerfile.